# Connection reset error for large payloads

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I have a very basic test application which serves bytes from memory and gives it back to the client.

Whenever i try to send the request for byte size which is of over 2 GB i get a connection reset error in my server code and a 502 error in my chrome console. Below 2 GB it is working fine.

In my client side i execute java script which i execute from the browser. This basically executes an XMLHTTPRequest , gets the response (stores in browser memory) and asks for a save.

Would like to know why the error is happening. Is it because the memory limit for a browser tab gets exceeded  ?

Below is the servlet or server side code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
 try {
String param = request.getParameter("size");
if (param != null) {

  int kByte = Integer.parseInt(param);

  response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
  response.setContentLength(kByte * 1024);

  ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

  long size = 0;
  while (size < kByte) {
    random.nextBytes(buffer);
    outputStream.write(buffer);
    size += 1;
  }

  outputStream.flush();

  return;
}
 }catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     response.sendError(500, e.getMessage());
     return;
 }
```

}

Below is my test client side java script code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Titillium Web";
    font-size: 15px;
}

#demo-container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}

#download-button {
    background-color: white;
    color: #2980b9;
    border: 2px solid #2980b9;
    font-family: inherit;
    outline: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: inherit;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#start-download {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

#download-progress-container {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 4px;
    display: none;
    height: 20px;
}

#download-progress {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

#save-file {
    color: #2980b9;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#save-file:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="demo-container">
    <button id="download-button">Download</button>
    <div id="download-ui-container">
        <div id="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
        <div id="download-progress-container"><div id="download-progress"></div></div>
        <a id="save-file">Save File</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

var _OBJECT_URL;

document.querySelector('#download-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

       request.onload = function () {
       _OBJECT_URL = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);

            document.querySelector('#save-file').setAttribute('href', _OBJECT_URL);
            document.querySelector('#save-file').setAttribute('download', 'networkTester');

            document.querySelector('#save-file').style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector('#download-progress-container').style.display = 'none';

            setTimeout(function() {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(_OBJECT_URL);

                document.querySelector('#download-button').style.display = 'block';
                document.querySelector('#save-file').style.display = 'none';
            }, 60*1000);
       }


    request.responseType = 'blob';
    //request.open('get', 'img.jpeg'); 


    request.open('get', 'server url?size=4000000');

    request.send(); 
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Stack trace on the server side

```
    2019-03-20T10:32:28.501+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:833)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:738)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:399)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:377)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.saurav.cpcftester.NetworkTester.doGet(NetworkTester.java:52)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:364)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:170)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.xs.java.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:66)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.xs.security.UserInfoValve.invoke(UserInfoValve.java:19)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.xs.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:43)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.xs.logging.catalina.RuntimeInfoValve.invoke(RuntimeInfoValve.java:40)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:50)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:478)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1306)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:726)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:496)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:434)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:623)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:127)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:225)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:602)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:352)
2019-03-20T10:32:28.502+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   ... 39 more
```

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: It is not your browser when there is an error on the serverside. Check your webserver configuration for a max request/response size. Is it an option to split the data to multiple requests?

Comment: I am on Tomcat and there is no setting like that for response size...i see some problem with client side

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that you met an integer overflow. Specifically, the line:

```
response.setContentLength(kByte * 1024);
```

may accept a signed integer range, so `2^31-1  = (2147483647 bytes)` which in your case may be causing overflow.

You can attempt to fix it like this:

```
long length = kByte * 1024; 
if (length <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) 
{ 
  response.setContentLength((int)length); 
} 
else 
{ 
  response.addHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(length)); 
}
```

as explained in the [reference](http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.com/2012/07/file-download-java-servlet-example-2gb.html).

Comment: @Niver...thanks for the response...i did the changes as you mentioned but still getting the same error

Comment: @saurav Please include the details of the exception you are getting

Comment: i have updated my initial post with the stacktrace...i am getting connection reset error when i using the outputstream.write in my code

Comment: The following link is similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768273/connection-dropped-by-client-when-serving-large-files-for-download-java-jersey and is solved still by setting the `Content-Length` header

Comment: thanks again...i am already setting the content length header