# Python requests post data too large

Tags: python, python-requests

```
def request_post(url, payload, headers):
    requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

request_post('mywebserver.com', ['a', 'b'])
```

When `payload` becomes a list of thousands of string, server throws a ClientAbortException.
Is there something that needs to be configured from the client side to be able to send a large post data?

Answer (score 1):

The error points to a connection being dropped by the client. it can happen due to a variety of reasons. [Some reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839314/clientabortexception-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-socket)

Specifically for a large file transfer, sometimes the length header is important to let the client know to keep streaming the payload. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768273/connection-dropped-by-client-when-serving-large-files-for-download-java-jersey)

You can try adding a header :

`"Content-Length" : <length in bytes>`